# Accessing Servlet from android httpclient programs getting connection refused?

Tags: java, android, servlets, httpclient

While I access the localhost servlet from android httpclient utils I am getting `connection refused` error. The servlet is running fine, but I am getting error.

This is the code:

```
String dmurl="http://127.0.0.1:9090/DataManagerProject/DMServlet";                                  
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet hrtreq = new HttpGet(dmurl);
HttpResponse resp = httpClient.execute(hrtreq);
String output = EntityUtils.toString(resp.getEntity());
```

I am getting following error `org.apache.http.conn.httphostconnectexception connection to refused`

Answer (score 1):

if you are using emulator to run your app for local server. mention the local ip as `10.0.2.2` and have to give **Internet permission** into your app

For more details, please refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#networkaddresses).

Also, **Turn Off the firewall and any anti-virus application in your PC**

Answer (score 0):

Check whether you have internet access enabled in your emulator and in your application

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

To access internet data of the device or emulator from your application add the above line in your manifest xml file.Also check the servlet mapping is proper in your the servlet project.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your servlet runs on your computer the reason you can't get a connection is because your using the wrong IP. 127.0.0.1 is a loopback address meaning that if you connect to 127.0.0.1 on your Android device, it will try to connect to the Android device.

To make it work you have to find the IP address of the computer which runs the servlet and use that in the URL instead.
In addition make sure you have given the Internet permission to your app.